# How to know the template type in the template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

here is an exemple :

```
template< typename T >
class A {
public :
    A(void) {
      this->_tab = ???[x];  
    }

private:
T*     _tab;

};
```

I would like to initialize my array with x elements but how to get the type of my template (i tried  but it's not working ).

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` ?

Comment: That's a pointer, not an array. You want `std::vector<T>` (or possibly `new T[x]` if you enjoy debugging memory leaks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just this should work.

```
this->_tab = new T[x];
```